# While loop in ubuntu crash after few iteration

Tags: bash, loops, ubuntu, while-loop

I have a file with 1000s of lines that looks like this

`978_Ad2_01000.fnc
979_Ad2_01001.fnc
97_Ad2_00098.fnc
981_Ad2_01003.fnc
982_Ad2_01004.fnc
983_Ad2_01005.fnc
984_Ad2_01006.fnc
985_Ad2_01007.fnc
986_Ad2_01008.fnc
988_Ad2_01010.fnc
98_Ad2_00099.fnc`

I would like to create as many folders as the lines I have in the file.
I wrote this small loop:

```
#! /bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line
do
    mkdir "$line"
done < ~/Desktop/*.txt
```

I would like to iterate this command for multiple .txt files present in my dir. This is the reason why I parse

```
 < ~/Desktop/*.txt.
```

The problem is that it reads and creates only few (5) folders and then stops.
I am sure it is something quite trivial, but I do not really get it.

Comment: Why are you looking in `*.txt` ?

Comment: it should be the file containing the above lines. I would like to iterate for multiple .txt files

Comment: Is there perhaps more than one `.txt` file in `~/Desktop`?

Comment: @Wintermute, Yes I would like to iterate to multiple files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot redirect from multiple files with `<`. Instead, you can use

```
cat ~/Desktop/*.txt | while IFS= read -r line; do
  mkdir "$line"
done
```

Or simply

```
cat ~/Desktop/*.txt | xargs -d '\n' mkdir
```

`cat` will concatenate the files it is given and write them to its stdout, so that you have a single file descriptor from which the contents of all files can be read and that you can use as the endpoint of a pipe to the loop's (or xargs') stdin.